# Unexpected keyword argument 'simple_zipcode'

Tags: python, zipcode

search = uszipcode.SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=False)

*The line above pulls up an unexpected keyword argument. I have the uszipcode module already installed.*

Comment: @luk2302, according to [the docs](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/01-Usage-Example/index.html) that is a valid kwarg.

Comment: in that case OP maybe installed the wrong version of the library or the docs are outdated

Comment: As it turns out, the docs are outdated.

Comment: I guess the example is outdated. They just indicate in a previous example to use it this way: `search = SearchEngine(simple_or_comprehensive=SearchEngine.SimpleOrComprehensiveArgEnum.simple)`. [Link to the docs](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/01-Usage-Example/index.html#simple-vs-comprehensive-zipcode-database).

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

```py
from uszipcode import SearchEngine

sr = SearchEngine()
z = sr.by_zipcode("10001")
print(z)

z = sr.by_zipcode(10001)
print(z)
```

there are a whole bunch or examples here (in the docs):
https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/01-Usage-Example/index.html

Caveat:  i am assuming that the docs are up to date as some of the comments to the original question suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code as the doc is outdated

```
    def __init__(
        self,
        simple_or_comprehensive: SimpleOrComprehensiveArgEnum = SimpleOrComprehensiveArgEnum.simple,
        db_file_path: typing.Union[str, None] = None,
        download_url: typing.Union[str, None] = None,
        engine: Engine = None,
    ):
```